# NOT in WHERE Clause does not seem to be working

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to exclude results from a query and I am making use of "NOT". When I test the where clause with only the NOT statement the results display correctly. Once I add the other conditions - it no longer excludes the specified items.

```
...
WHERE Group IN ('01', '02') 
    AND ImgLink <> '' 
    AND Qty > 0 
    AND NOT (Description = 'cat') OR QtyPO > 0
...
```

**Expected Results**

I expect all results where the following:

- Description is everything else but "cat"
- And is in group 1 or 2
- ImgLink is set
- QTY & QtyPO is more than 0.

Comment: The operator AND has higher precedence than OR. Use parentheses to adjust your requirement.

Comment: @user7294900 I guess depending on your RDBMS' handling of NULL values, `NOT (Description = 'cat')` might actually return different rows than `Description <> 'cat'`, but I might be wrong

Comment: ***`QTY & QtyPO is more than 0`***. Then why **`OR`** `QtyPO > 0`? It should be **`AND`** `QtyPO > 0`.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt: No, description NULL is excluded with either expression.

Comment: Your `WHERE` translate to `WHERE (Group IN ('01', '02') AND ImgLink <> '' AND Qty > 0 AND NOT (Description = 'cat')) OR QtyPO > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want   `Qty > 0 OR QtyPO > 0`
and the others  condition  the you should wrap this condition properly using ()

```
      WHERE Group IN ('01', '02') 
      AND ImgLink <> ''
      AND ( Qty > 0 OR QtyPO > 0 )
      AND NOT Description = 'cat'
```